# How to handle UISearchResultsTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am getting UISearchResultsTableView as tableView of

```
(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

How do I handle this. I can not refer UISearchResultsTableView on the documentation.

I initialized the search display controller from my view controller (which is an instance of UITableViewController) as describe on http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Is there any thing to do more than in documentation??? Please help..

Answer (score 1):

UISearchResultsTableView is a private subclass of UITableView, which is why it's not in the documentation.  As the method declaration you pasted in indicates, you should be treating tableView as a UITableView.

You need to populate the tableView in the usual manner (using the UITableViewDataSource methods, such as –tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, etc.).  Get the actual text being searched for by requesting [searchBar text] from the search display controller.

You can find out when a user has typed by implementing the [UISearchDisplayDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods.

That's a general overview, and it's all documented in the link you mentioned and related documents.  If you would like more specific help you will need to post code and a more specific question.